# kafka 2.12 version failed kafka-logs is not in the form of topic-partition

Tags: apache-kafka

Here is a detailed log:

[image]

配置文件

```
[root@mast-1 ~]# grep '^[a-zA-Z]' /opt/kafka/config/server.properties 
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.11:9092
num.network.threads=6
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/opt/kafka/logs/
num.partitions=6
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=60
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=10.0.0.11:2181,10.0.0.12:2181,10.0.0.14:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

> ERROR There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory
>   /opt/kafka_2.12-2.0.1/logs/kafka-logs, 'kafka-logs' is not in the form
>   of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for
>   deletion). Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain
>   Kafka topic data. (kafka.log.LogManager) [2018-11-30 04:16:29,108]
>   ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup.
>   Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory
>   /opt/kafka_2.12-2.0.1/logs/kafka-logs, 'kafka-logs' is not in the form
>   of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for
>   deletion).

Comment: Sounds like some data was placed into that folder that `is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete`... Please show `ls -al  /opt/kafka_2.12-2.0.1/logs/kafka-logs`

Comment: @cricket  Hello, then I will delete that directory. 我之前有截图 我在源问题那里添加了

Comment: Can you please post your server.properties file in an **[edit]**?

Comment: @cricket 您好 已经修改了！

Comment: Sorry, can you please translate your posts?

Comment: Hmm. Your error is not matching your config `log.dirs=/opt/kafka/logs/`

Comment: @cricket_007 
Sorry, kafka in sorry log.dirs=/opt/kafka/logs is a soft link pointing to the text path

Comment: And how did you get a subdirectory `kafka-logs` within that? A directory that `is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete`